# Full width Submenu

Tags: html, css

I want a full width Sub categorie bar with the sub sub categorie under the sub categorie which is always visible. Well a images says more than words.

Beneath you find the

I want something like this,

[image: I want this]

I have:
CSS MENU

```
/* Sub menu */
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul li { 
  background: #469e92; 
  display: block; 
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul li > a{ 
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
/* Sub menu */
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrC11/7sad1cpj/)